# Extjs - Loading data to center region in border layout

Tags: java, html, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS and trying to experiment with the border layout.
I can't seem to find a way to load ext components to the center region.

Everything is contained in a viewport:

```
new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    items: [
```

I've set the west region with a treepanel as such:

```
xtype: 'panel',
region: 'west',
width: 200,
items: [{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    height: 500,
    border: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    width: 199,
    autoWidth: true,
    id: 'navtree',
    root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
        expanded: true,
        children: [{
            text: 'Users',
            expanded: false,
            children: [{
                id: 'adduser',
                text: 'Add User',
                leaf: true,
        },{
        id: 'deleteuser',
        text: 'Delete User',
        leaf: true
```

and so on.....
The navtree displays properly.

The center region was setup as:

```
{
xtype: 'panel',
region: 'center',
autoScroll: true,
contentEl: 'centercontents'
}
```

I initially loaded external web pages like so:

```
Ext.getCmp('navtree').on('click', function(node){
  if(node.id == 'adduser'){Ext.get("centercontents").load({ url: "/adduser" });}
```

with "centercontents" being a div in the main html file.

That worked fine also, but now I would like to extend this so that
on click of the "adduser" node, display a form to the center region
directly ... bypassing loading any sort of additional html file.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.
(Example code even better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely creating a new instance of that form object.  When that happens as you have coded it above, a duplicate DOM ID for the `addsimpleuser` object is being created.  This collision is likely what is causing the form to dissappear.

A simple check to see if that object exists before creating it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Making progress on this, but have a new problem.

I've changed the center region to:

```
{
xtype: 'panel',
region: 'center',
autoScroll: true,
id: 'centercontents'
}
```

And changed the click to:

```
Ext.getCmp('navtree').on('click', function(node){
    if(node.id == 'adduser')
        {
        var content = Ext.getCmp('centercontents');
        content.removeAll(true);
        var container = content.add(simpleadduser);
        content.doLayout();
        container.show();
        }
```

where simpleadduser is a form.

On page load, the navtree displays properly, and clicking on the adduser
node loads the form into the center reqion. However, clicking the adduser
node a second time makes the form disappear. Any reason it would not reload
itself?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line: `content.removeAll(true);`